# Highcharts: Looping JSON into Series Data

Tags: javascript, loops, highcharts

I am trying to loop a JSON string into my series data. However, I don't seem to be getting the data. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonStrng.lowUsage.length; i++) {
    options.series[0].data = jsonStrng.healthy[i];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};

for (var j = 0; j < jsonStrng.healthy.length; j++) {
    options.series[1].data = jsonStrng.lowUsage[j];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};

for (var k = 0; k < jsonStrng.terrible.length; k++) {
    options.series[2].data = jsonStrng.terrible[k];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};

for (var ii = 0; ii < jsonStrng.buggy.length; ii++) {
    options.series[3].data = jsonStrng.buggy[ii];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/231Lbzq7/1/)

Comment: Point of education, after you execute this line: `var jsonStrng = JSON.parse(str);` you are no longer dealing with JSON.  You have an object with several arrays inside of it.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle -- all of your JavaScript is inside a function `DeviceHealthDeploymentUtilization` that isn't actually be called anywhere.

Comment: There's actually a reason for that on the java side. It requires the named function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below code :

Create an array and fill it with the data while looping into json array.Finally assign series.data to that array

```
var healthyData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsonStrng.lowUsage.length; i++) {
 healthyData.push(jsonStrng.healthy[i]); 
}
options.series[0].data = healthyData;
```

Do this for all 3 series data and don't call chart function until all series are filled with data .After last series call following function

```
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

If you share your json data,. I will update your fiddle to make it working.